# Opening another application using a dialog - is it possible?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have an idea to open at my application dialog another application for example Chrome. I mean smth like container where will be placed Chrome and also with ability to send some data like link. Right now I'm using intents with chooser, but it will be very good to use dialog or dialog-fragment for this task. Thank you for useful advice and information.

Comment: Are you trying to open an external app inside a dialog from your own app?

Comment: @devgianlu, yes if it is possible.

Comment: It's not possible.